The PMIx server's listener thread failed to start. We cannot continue
I am using termux with ubuntu. I need to run a python program. However i get the below error.
root@localhost:~/capstone/mpi# mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 1 python3 index.py
[localhost:18945] opal_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:18945] pmix_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:18945] ptl_tool: problems getting address for index 122 (kernel index -1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The PMIx server's listener thread failed to start. We cannot
continue.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Python Code:
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
worker = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

print(f"Worker {worker} of Size {size}")

Please Help Me out. Many thanks.
I Executed the above code with the command, and gave me the above error
mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 1 python3 index.py


I'm getting the same issue. Did you get any solution?

I just ran into this problem on macOS, same error even though the command ran before with no problem. The only thing which changed: I wasn‘t connected to any network.
Apparently, on macOS the byte transfer layer, or BTL, used to run the processes locally is tcp, which is only available while connected to a network (see this answer to a similar question).
You should check what BTL is used in your setup and maybe try to use a different one by setting --mca btl_tcp_if_include lo0 for example.
